# VSCode - messy unittest configuration for django project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm using python 3.6.5, django 2.0.3 and VSCode 1.21.1.

In my project I have couple test files (`test_*.py`) in the following location `app/tests/`. I'm able to simply run them using cmd: `python manage.py test app.tests`. I wanted to use VSCode tests debugging so I decided to configure built-in unittest handler.

First I edited workspace `settings.json` file adding following code:

```
"python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-s",
    "app.tests",
    "test_*.py",
```

It turned out that `__init__.py` files are required both for `app` and `tests` folders in order to detect files containing tests. I recently switched to Python 3 and was really happy `__init__.py` files are no longer a requirement ([PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#rationale)). But yeah, I had to add them just to make test detection work.

Then I found out that without calling `django.setup()` and setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the first place I still won't be able to run my tests. Therefore I had to add the following code at the beginning of every test file:

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyAwesomeWebApp.settings')
django.setup()
```

Is it all really required or there is some other way to configure unittest in VSCode?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. So, I have manage to run django test in VS with next configs in debug configurations.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Django Test",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "args": [
    "test",
     ],
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
},
```

I can use breakpoints and explore test variables state. So I hope it will help you or anyone.